Django не находит изображения
Я определил следующие настройки в settings.py:

имею следующую структуру проекта:

При переходе на эти url:
127.0.0.1:8000/media/5JTeFpjl95w.jpg

127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/5JTeFpjl95w.jpg*текст курсивом*

Мне лишь возвращается 404. Как это можно исправить?

Во-первых, все тексты должны быть текстами, а не скриншотами. Во-вторых, Django не занимается раздачей файлов, это задача веб-сервера

Что бы Django сайт мог открыть картинку находящуюся на сервере, добавьте следующий код в urls.py:
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)


Если режим DEBAG = True в  settings.py, тогда необходимо в корневом urls проекта ПОСЛЕ(!часто включают в само поле!) поля
    urlpatterns[
..........
    ]

указать следующее:
if settings.DEBUG:
        urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

также необходимо проверить настройки статик и медиа:
(к примеру)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join.(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join.(BASE_DIR, 'media/')

